# HTML & PHP -Tornar um botao de log in em log out

Tags: php, html

Tenho o meu codigo em PHP criado tanto para o log in como para o log out, confesso que já li varios artigos no google como transformar um botao log in em log out mas confesso que o li não ajudou em nada, estou aqui para pedir se alguem me pode ilucidar como fazer. A minha pagina index(VER FOTO) tem um botao chamado member area que eu gostaria de se torna-se um botao chamado log out quando o usuario fizesse log in.
[image: MEMBER AREA]
Codigo actualizado:

```
[![<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu
             ">
      <li><a href="index.html"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Books Categories</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="bookcomputing.php">Computing</a></li>
        <li><a href="bookromance.php">Romance</a></li>
        <li><a href="bookfiction.php">Fiction</a></li>
         <li><a href="booknonfiction.php">Non-Fiction</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    <div id="memberarea">
      <?php

if (!isset($_SESSION\['email'\])) {
    echo "<a href='memberarea.html'>Member area</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>"; 
} 

?>
      <a href="adminarea.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Admin area</a>
</div>
    <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="author's name, title">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
<p> Welcome to Galaxy Book Store website, this website was created for people who really enjoy reading all sort of books.</p> 
<p>Here you can find a huge amount of books.</p>
</body>
</html>
<footer>
    <p> &#174; Galaxy Books Store</p>

</footer>][2]][2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque o "*Member Area*" por algo como:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='login.php'>Member Area</a>"; 
} 

?>
```

**Funcionamento**

Se a sessão `email` existir, ele exibirá "*Log Out*". Se não existir, ele exibirá "*Member Area*".

Comment: Anderson I solução que voce apresenta, voce sugere que eu coloque essa informação em login.php ou em memberarea.html (acabei de editar meu comentario para colocar o codigo memberarea.html.)

Comment: A solução não é minha, eu apenas melhorei a formatação. Mas este código deve ir na página onde você exibe o link *Member Area* que você deseja que mude para *Logout*.

Comment: @DianaMadeira em nenhuma das duas. Você colocará este código em seu menu.

Comment: que menu VME? desculpe mas não tou entendendo

Comment: No lugar desse seu botão "Member Area" coloque o código que falei

Comment: <a href="memberarea.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Member area </a> <br>   este é o botao que eu tenho neste momento, ja substitui e nao deu muito certo

Comment: Informe o ocorrido

Comment: atualizei o codigo onde coloco o codigo que voce sugeriu e adicionei uma foto onde mostra o resultado.

Comment: Você alterou todo o código que mandei. Peço que coloque exatamente como informei.
No início da página, adiciona um <?php  session_start(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o esquema de sessões do PHP.

Quando o usuário estiver logado, você deve criar uma sessão mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'login do usuário'
?>
```

Isso fará com que o browser saiba que o usuário fez seu login.

Após isso, você deve colocar uma verificação de sessão no local onde quer alterar o botão:

```
<div id="memberarea">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>";
        }else {
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>"; 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```